# Symfony 2 - FOSUserBundle - Add fields bdd

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, fosuserbundle

I use Symfony 2 and I would manage my users FOSUserBundle. I set up the bundle, all works. Only the fields FOSUserBundle offers not enough for me. I would like to add more fields.

So I modified my entity that inherits FOSUserBundle and add two fields. I managed to put these two fields in my registration form (register). But even after a *php app / console doctrine: schema: update --force* added fields do not appear in my db. Nothing to do, the rest bdd the default FOSUserBundle. Moreover it is quite strange because after my command in Terminal, I get *Nothing to update - your database is already in sync with the current entity metadata.* in response.

My code :

```
    <?php

namespace FP\UserBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="lastname", type="text")
     */
    private $lastname;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="lastname", type="text")
     */
    private $pays;

    /**
     * Get pays
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPays()
    {
        return $this->pays;
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set lastname
     *
     * @param string $lastname
     * @return User
     */
    public function setLastname($lastname)
    {
        $this->lastname = $lastname;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get lastname
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getLastname()
    {
        return $this->lastname;
    }
}
```

.

```
<?php

namespace FP\UserBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use FOS\UserBundle\Form\Type\RegistrationFormType as BaseType;

class RegistrationFormType extends BaseType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        parent::buildForm($builder, $options);

        // add your custom field
        $builder
            ->add('lastname')
            ->add('pays')
        ;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'fp_user_registration';
    }
}
```

.

```
# src/FP/UserBundle/Resources/config/services.yml
services:
    FP_user.registration.form.type:
        class: FP\UserBundle\Form\Type\RegistrationFormType
        arguments: [%fos_user.model.user.class%]
        tags:
            - { name: form.type, alias: fp_user_registration }
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: both `$lastname` and `$pays` are mapped to a `lastname` column.  Not sure if thats the problem, but it wont help. Also, have you changed `%fos_user.model.user.class%` to use your new entity class?

Comment: How should I have done?

Comment: youll have settings on config.yml or parameters.yml for `fos_user`. youll need to point that to your entity class.

Comment: Yes, it was done:
fos_user:
    db_driver:     orm                      
    firewall_name: main                      
    user_class:    FP\UserBundle\Entity\User
    registration:
        form:
            type: fp_user_registration

Comment: Nobody has a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I think my mistake may come my app / security.yml file ...

```
security:
    encoders:
        FP\UserBundle\Entity\User: sha512

    # http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-user-providers
    providers:
        main:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username
        in_memory:
            memory: ~

    firewalls:
        # disables authentication for assets and the profiler, adapt it according to your needs
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        main:
            pattern:        ^/
            anonymous:      true
            provider:       main
            form_login:
                login_path: fos_user_security_login
                check_path: fos_user_security_check
            logout:
                path:       fos_user_security_logout
                target:     /
            remember_me:
                key:        %secret%
```

Answer (score 0):

My error came from a file in User.orm Resources/config/doctrine UserBundle my bundle. So I deleted.